# Determine MTU of an IPv6 path

Tags: macos, command-line, ping, ipv6

For IPv4, MTU can be found with sweep-ping:

```
ping -g 1464 -G 1508 -c 2 -h 1 -D 1.1.1.1
```

or by manually decreasing ping after a huge ping:

```
ping -c1 -D -s 1472 1.1.1.1
```

For IPv6, the easiest method I'm aware of is to use ping or something else then check `netstat -narWl -f inet6` and find the relevant IP address. (edit: which doesnt even determine that for a path but for an interface only. so the result is strictly an upper bound)

Is there a more practical way of determining the MTU of an IPv6 path?